# Python/MySQLdb troubles on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, raspberry-pi

I'm running into some trouble running python/mysqldb on my raspberry pi.  This is a pretty simple script, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.  The "SELECT * FROM..." runs with no problem, but I can't seem to update the table with new values.  The script runs without throwing errors, but when I ctrl-C, it gives me this:

> Exception _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now") in bound method DictCursor.__del of MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor object at 0x19dfd90

Here's my script:

```
    dhost = "localhost"
    duser = "root"
    dname = "rpi"
    dpass = "datPassword"

    import MySQLdb

    try:
        con = MySQLdb.connect(dhost,duser,dpass,dname);
        cur = con.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
        sys.exit(1)


    def websiteToSensor():
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM homeauto WHERE changedby = 'website'")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            cur.execute("UPDATE homeauto SET changedby = 'script' WHERE id = '%s'",(row["id"]))
        return

    while True:
        websiteToSensor()
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why my table isn't updating?  Thanks!

****EDIT: SOLUTION**********

Thanks to Martijn Pieters, here's my new websiteToSensor() code:

```
    def websiteToSensor():
        cur = con.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM homeauto WHERE changedby = 'website'")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        num = int(cur.rowcount)
        if num > 0:
            for row in rows:
                cur.execute("UPDATE homeauto SET changedby = 'script' WHERE id = '%s'",(row["id"]))
            con.commit()
            cur.close()
            con.commit()
        else:
            cur.close()
            con.commit()
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try committing your changes:

```
def websiteToSensor():
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM homeauto WHERE changedby = 'website'")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        cur.execute("UPDATE homeauto SET changedby = 'script' WHERE id = '%s'",(row["id"]))
    con.commit()
    return
```

Comment: I would also suggest a small `time.sleep` in the while loop.

Comment: I...I spent hours on this.  I hate you for your simple solution, but I love you for helping me with this.  The con.commit() was all I needed.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's another stumper for you... This code only works once.  Ideally, this will continue to poll a dynamically changed mysql database and update the table accordingly.  However, after the script runs websiteToSensor() one time, it's not finding the new rows that have changedby = 'website'.  Any ideas why it's not properly reading the table?

Comment: I suspect you need to create a new cursor for every run of `websiteToSensor()` to get a new transaction context.